# Training a model purely on weak labels

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, supervised-learning

I have read a couple of papers now use rules-based system to create weak labels and then train a BERT-based model only using these weak labels. Both studies have reported better performances on manually labelled gold-standard test data.

However, I just don't follow the logic here. I understand distant supervision and all that. It's been around for a while now. I just don't understand if your model (BERT or not) is only trained on these weak labels then you are treating them as "ground-truth", and more importantly, don't you already know how to create "ground-truth" (by the rules-based system) ??? What's the point of the 2nd step?

Even though the performances on test data are better. It doesn't convince me your ML model (from the 2nd step) have learnt something beyond the weak labels you fed to it.

The only argument I find has some merits is that you basically treat the BERT-based model already as a zero-shot classifier and you are fine-tuning it with weak labels. I am just confused. Can someone pls enlighten me? Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: Please add links to the papers that you mention, otherwise it's hard to know exactly what this is about. Based only on your description I'd say that I agree with your interpretation, but it depends what the authors do exactly.

Comment: I can't find the other paper. But here is one (https://arxiv.org/pdf/2101.09244.pdf). See Figure 1. I didn't post any particular paper because it seems to me a pattern across different studies, and the logic is the same and a clear one, i.e. training a ml classifier only on weak labels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on a quick read of the paper linked in the comment:

> I just don't understand if your model (BERT or not) is only trained on these weak labels then you are treating them as "ground-truth",

Correct, but only for the training: the model is trained to recognize the labels obtained with a "quick and dirty" method.

> and more importantly, don't you already know how to create "ground-truth" (by the rules-based system) ??? What's the point of the 2nd step?

No, because the real ground truth they are interested in is not those from the "quick and dirty" method. If they were, it would indeed be sufficient to run their rule-based system. The goal is to predict the labels obtained in what the authors call the "Gold Standard Corpus", which was manually annotated and never seen by the model.

Typically the quick and dirty method will result in some classification errors. The point of tuning the model with these labels is to see if the model can extrapolate from these low-quality labels to high-quality labels. This ability to generalize beyond the training data is based on the underlying semantic information contained in the original BERT-like model. For example this model might be able to associate a specific sport like swimming with "physical activity", even though the weak supervision doesn't contain this association.

Comment: Toward that end, it seems really important to report the scores (and maybe even a deeper analysis) of the rule-based system on the GSC test set, which I didn't see on the linked paper.

Comment: @BenReiniger absolutely, I think this paper doesn't do a great job at proving that their approach is relevant.

Comment: Thanks for your responses, both of you.